# Help with convergence and divergence

Tags: sequences-and-series

When you are determining if a series converges you can pick any term in the series and ignore all the other terms in front of it. Why are you allowed to  start at any term in the series to determine convergence?

Comment: Because you go arbitrarily far in the future. The first terms don't matter anymore, if you can go as far as you want in the future. If you start a little bit later, then just run your process a bit longer.

Answer (score 1):

Because the sum of the first $k$ terms (for any fixed finte integer $k$) is finite, so subtracting that value from the series sum does not affect whether the sum diverges of not.

Answer (score 0):

The definition of a sequence $(a_n)$ converging to some limit $a$, means that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=a$.  In other words, we are only concerned with the behavior of the sequence as we go arbitrarily far into its terms, regardless of how it started out.  Kind of like, if one skydiver jumps from a plane while the other one just drops out, they'll both have the same terminal velocity, regardless of the differences at the beginning.